# Laravel Filesystem: Managing Folders in Google Drive API

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, google-drive-api

I am following this tutorial:-
https://gist.github.com/sergomet/f234cc7a8351352170eb547cccd65011

My Laravel application requires files to be organized inside a folder. So, whenever a file is uploaded it should be saved inside a folder that it belongs to.

Before uploading a file, I must check whether the folder exists or not. In Laravel, I have used this method to list all the directories at root.

```
$directories = Storage::directories();
```

However, it returns a list of alphanumeric unique ids with no references to the human readable names. I don't want to create duplicate folder even though it is possible in Google drive.

So, how do we get list of `folder names` along with reference id?

Answer (score 3):

The proper way you should create a lookup table and store the `id` and `folder names`. Otherwise if you are querying the folder name you will need to fetch the meta data by id:

```
$metadata = Storage::disk('gdrive')->getAdapter()->getMetadata($folderId);
```

The metadata format can be check [here](https://github.com/nao-pon/flysystem-google-drive/blob/master/src/GoogleDriveAdapter.php#L823). You may notice that Google Drive is ID based filesystem, so this connector need ID based path.

Comment: how can I do the same thing for a file id?